# Is there a way to evaluate function from Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am getting some 'quantum' behaviour from combination of knockout.js and Jquery Mobile UI (Accordion with pagination) I am observing one thing while code does something completely different.
I am looking for a way to evaluate function (check screenshot) in Chrome developer tools, or if you can propose any workaround that would get me $parent.IsExpanded value.
[image]

When I am evaluating value in console

```
ko.contextFor($('.ui-collapsible-content:not(.ui-collapsible-content-collapsed)').contents().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType == 8;
    })[0]).$parent.IsExpanded()
```

I get 'true'

While visually inspecting the code (screenshot) I can see 'If' binding not being evaluated e.g being 'false'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to do this, I (temporarily) add a global reference to my viewModel, so I can access it in the console:

```
var myViewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
window.myViewModel = myViewModel;
```

Then in Chrome:

```
myViewModel.IsExpanded()
```